# Can I add a variable into warnings message?

Tags: python

I have an application that will open many files and will convert these files into a pandas data frame. I want to ensure that all pandas' data frames have the same structure so I want to create a warning if the number of the column is not equal that 10. I also want to know which file was the one that arise the warning.

How can I introduce the file_name into the warning message?

```
def load_data(self):

    some code

    file_name = file_name
    if df.shape[1] !=10:
        warning.warns("File_name is wrong"
    return pandas_df2
```

Comment: Can you use an f-string? `f"Filename {file_name} is wrong"`?

Comment: As a follow-up, does anybody know why this isn't standard practice? Many packages I use will throw errors with unhelpful messages that could include the information about the variable that caused the error to be thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use format strings as below

```
wrld = 'world'
A = 2
B = 5
print(f'Hello {wrld} {A + B} times')
```

output :

```
Hello world 7 times
```

pretty much anything in curly braces is python code

Comment: IMO this is not all there it is to warnings.

I am at a point where if i add a variable inside warnings.warn(variable) it will not give me the variable contents